# Read binary (.hgt) file in C (Migrate code from C++ to C)

Tags: c++, c

I'm attempting an application that uses binary data from ".hgt" formatted file. I found a soltuion in C++, but I can't figure out how to translate that solution to C. Each value in the file is type signed short int and there are 1201x1201 values.

```
const int SIZE = 1201;
signed short int matrix[SIZE][SIZE] = {0};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    using namespace std;

    ifstream file("N49E013.hgt", ios::in|ios::binary);    

    unsigned char buffer[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j) 
        {
            if(!file.read( reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer), sizeof(buffer) ))
            {
                cout << "Error reading file!" << endl;
                system("PAUSE");
                return -1;
            }
            matrix[i][j] = (buffer[0] << 8) | buffer[1];       
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mainly, you simply need to swap out the `std` methods for the `stdio.h` functions, as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 1201
signed short int matrix[SIZE][SIZE] = {0};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("N49E013.hgt", "rb");    

    unsigned char buffer[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j) 
        {
            if (fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, fp) != 1)
            {
                printf("Error reading file!\n");
                system("PAUSE");
                return -1;
            }
            matrix[i][j] = (buffer[0] << 8) | buffer[1];       
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: The correct approach to check if `fread()` succeeded is `fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, fp) < 1`, by the way.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for help.

Comment: @H2CO3 In practice the return value on error or eof is 0, so that's just an old (bad) habit.  But you're right that the return value not equaling the count parameter is the documented error/eof indicator.  +1 and code fixed accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

0) At the top

#include <stdio.h>

1) Remove the inline declarations and move them to the top after main(){

2) Remove the using namespace

3) Replace ifstream ... with

```
FILE* file = fopen("N49E013.hgt", "rb");
```

4) Replace file.read... with

```
fread(buffer, 2, 1, file);
```

5) Replace cout ... with

```
printf("Error reading file\n");
```

6) After the } for the loop, add

```
fclose(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

The C code is very similar, you just have to use stdio.h's fopen and fread instead.

See this example: http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-binary-file-io